# Q function chaining

Tags: javascript, function, q

```
function sum(a, b) {
    var defer = Q.defer();
    if (!a || !b) {
        defer.reject('error');
    } else {
        defer.resolve(a + b);
    }
    return defer.promise;
}
function sqrt(data) {
    var defer = Q.defer();
    defer.resolve(Math.sqrt(data));
    return defer.promise;
}
sum(8, 8)
    .then(sqrt())
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I don't want to use Q.fcall,  I want it this way. And my problem in the code is that I can't seem to pass arguments to `sqrt()` from `.then` . So it currently returns 16 (the sum of a + b), instead of 4.

Comment: When you have `foo(bar())`, `bar` is executed first and its return value is passed to `foo`. That's how JavaScript works and that behavior is the same,  not matter what kind of value `foo` expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum(8, 8).then(sqrt())
```

When this line is run, `sqrt()` is run with zero arguments and its *return value* is passed to `.then`.  What you want to pass is the *function* itself to `.then`, not call it.

```
sum(8, 8).then(sqrt)
```